# Photo sizing issues in wordpress

Tags: php, image, wordpress

Hi I am having trouble displaying my thumbnails to the actual size of the image.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="property_photo">
        <?php if (has_post_thumbnail($property->ID)){
            echo get_the_post_thumbnail(
            $property->ID,
            array(300,220),
            array('class' => 'post_thumbnail')
            );
            }
        ?>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.property_photo {
 float:left; 
 max-width:300px;
 min-height:220px;
}
```

functions.php:

```
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails'); // ENABLES POST THUMBNAILS
add_image_size( 'post-thumbnails', 300, 220, true );
add_image_size( 'bones-thumb-600', 600, 150, true );
add_image_size( 'bones-thumb-300', 300, 220, true );
```

It is displaying the proper width but not the proper height.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the string keyword instead of the 2-item array:

`get_the_post_thumbnail( $property->ID, 'post-thumbnails', array('class' => 'post_thumbnail') )`

Explanation: using an array will resize the original image, using the string will render the hard-cropped thumb

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail

Comment: If i'm not mistaken, using an array resizes the original, using the string will render the hard-cropped thumb

Comment: maybe update your answer with that reasoning, that way others can benefit from not only your answer but also the logic behind it, otherwise it doesnt make sense to others with no explanation IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Step1. Paste this function in your function.php file

```
function vt_resize( $attach_id = null, $img_url = null, $width, $height, $crop = false ) {

    // this is an attachment, so we have the ID
    if ( $attach_id ) {

        $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attach_id, 'full' );
        $file_path = get_attached_file( $attach_id );

    // this is not an attachment, let's use the image url
    } else if ( $img_url ) {

        $file_path = parse_url( $img_url );
        $file_path = ltrim( $file_path['path'], '/' );
        //$file_path = rtrim( ABSPATH, '/' ).$file_path['path'];

        $orig_size = getimagesize( $file_path );

        $image_src[0] = $img_url;
        $image_src[1] = $orig_size[0];
        $image_src[2] = $orig_size[1];
    }

    $file_info = pathinfo( $file_path );
    $extension = '.'. $file_info['extension'];

    // the image path without the extension
    $no_ext_path = $file_info['dirname'].'/'.$file_info['filename'];

    $cropped_img_path = $no_ext_path.'-'.$width.'x'.$height.$extension;

    // checking if the file size is larger than the target size
    // if it is smaller or the same size, stop right here and return
    if ( $image_src[1] > $width || $image_src[2] > $height ) {

        // the file is larger, check if the resized version already exists (for crop = true but will also work for crop = false if the sizes match)
        if ( file_exists( $cropped_img_path ) ) {

            $cropped_img_url = str_replace( basename( $image_src[0] ), basename( $cropped_img_path ), $image_src[0] );

            $vt_image = array (
                'url' => $cropped_img_url,
                'width' => $width,
                'height' => $height
            );

            return $vt_image;
        }

        // crop = false
        if ( $crop == false ) {

            // calculate the size proportionaly
            $proportional_size = wp_constrain_dimensions( $image_src[1], $image_src[2], $width, $height );
            $resized_img_path = $no_ext_path.'-'.$proportional_size[0].'x'.$proportional_size[1].$extension;            

            // checking if the file already exists
            if ( file_exists( $resized_img_path ) ) {

                $resized_img_url = str_replace( basename( $image_src[0] ), basename( $resized_img_path ), $image_src[0] );

                $vt_image = array (
                    'url' => $resized_img_url,
                    'width' => $new_img_size[0],
                    'height' => $new_img_size[1]
                );

                return $vt_image;
            }
        }

        // no cached files - let's finally resize it
        $new_img_path = image_resize( $file_path, $width, $height, $crop );
        $new_img_size = getimagesize( $new_img_path );
        $new_img = str_replace( basename( $image_src[0] ), basename( $new_img_path ), $image_src[0] );

        // resized output
        $vt_image = array (
            'url' => $new_img,
            'width' => $new_img_size[0],
            'height' => $new_img_size[1]
        );

        return $vt_image;
    }

    // default output - without resizing
    $vt_image = array (
        'url' => $image_src[0],
        'width' => $image_src[1],
        'height' => $image_src[2]
    );

    return $vt_image;
}
```

Step 2 is to display in you page. For that use this

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" alt="Read Moare about <?php the_title(); ?>" title="Read Moare about <?php the_title(); ?>" >
              <?php 
 $thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id(); 
 $image = vt_resize( $thumb,'' , 515, 700, true );
 ?>
              <img src="<?php echo $image[url]; ?>" width="<?php echo $image[width]; ?>" height="<?php echo $image[height]; ?>" /> </a>
```

..where 515 and 700  is the size. You can change this as you wish!